# Inputting a default image in case the src attribute of an html <img> is not valid?

Tags: html, image

Is there any way to render a default image in an HTML `<img>` tag, in case the `src` attribute is invalid (using only HTML)?  If not, what would be your lightweight way to work around it?

Comment: HTML has no fallback for broken images. You'd need to use JavaScript to find broken images and change their src attribute.

Comment: @Blixt - What if your client is MS Outlook or someother EMAIL reader and you don't have Javascript, and the object option does not work ... I presume the only solution is alt/text

Comment: Actually, Firefox has a *real fallback* for images that don’t load! It places the alternative Text of the image instead of the image, and even applies styling to it! I always liked this way as it took the _alternative text_ seriously.

Comment: Just a note about alt text: https://www.sitelint.com/blog/best-practices-for-writing-good-alt-text/

Answer (score 406, accepted):

You asked for an *HTML only* solution...

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Object Test</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>

<body>

  <p>
    <object data="https://stackoverflow.com/does-not-exist.png" type="image/png">
      <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/unified/sprites.svg?v=e5e58ae7df45" alt="Stack Overflow logo and icons and such">
    </object>
  </p>

</body>

</html>
```

Since the first image doesn't exist, the fallback (the sprites used on this web site*) will display. And if you're using a *really* old browser that doesn't support [`object`](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/special/object.html), it will ignore that tag and use the `img` tag. See [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=%3Cobject%3E) website for compatibility. This element is widely supported by all browsers from IE6+.

** Unless the URL for the image changed (again), in which case you'll probably see the alt text.*

Comment: It worked for me in IE8 after I put in the DTD for HTML 4.01.

Comment: This doesn't work if the non-existing image has `X-Frame-Options` set to `SAMEORIGIN` or a more permissive setting.

Comment: It works but if the link in object.data is not trusted, it can load all kind of stuff...

Comment: What I did was use a combination of these solutions. It turns out 1 solution is not enough because of various browser clients. This DOES point to perhaps the need for a HTML standard (update) to resolve this type of thing.

What I do is use a an alt/text styled with inline CSS for big characters AND javascript AND a background image. The javascript works on Chrome but does not work on Outlook. The alt/text with a background image shows up on Outlook.

<<

Comment: Element 'img' cannot be nested inside element 'object'.

Comment: @Matheus Sure it can. In HTML4 object can contain flow content (almost everything, including img), and in HTML5 it's transparent, meaning it can contain any valid HTML5.

Comment: This really slows down my site when I use it with 10+ images that are not existing. Looks like it crashes the php session.

Comment: onerror="this.src='error.jpg';this.onerror=null;" this might help

Comment: Doesn't work for <button><img /></button>... - can't click the button due to the object.

Comment: It worked for me ,
 onerror="this.src='error.jpg';this.onerror=null; this one is not working

Comment: Just a reminder to use `tabindex="-1"` on the `<object>` so that keyboard navigation doesn't have to stop at every image that uses this strategy.

Answer (score 395):

This works well for me. Maybe you wanna use JQuery to hook the event.

```
 <img src="foo.jpg" onerror="if (this.src != 'error.jpg') this.src = 'error.jpg';" alt="add alternative text here">
```

Updated with jacquargs error guard

**Updated: CSS only solution**
I recently saw [Vitaly Friedman](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/03/dirty-tricks-dark-corners-front-end-slides-pdf/) demo a great CSS solution I wasn't aware of. The idea is to apply the `content` property to the broken image. Normally `:after` or `:before` do not apply to images, but when they're broken, they're applied.

```
<img src="nothere.jpg" alt="add alternative text here">
<style>
img:before {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-image: url(ishere.jpg);
}
</style>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/uz2gmh2k/2/

As the fiddle shows, the broken image itself is not removed, but this will probably solve the problem for most cases without any JS nor gobs of CSS. If you need to apply different images in different locations, simply differentiate with a class: `.my-special-case img:before { ...`

Comment: Using the onerror event to catch broken images is as old as ... well, it's an old technique, and as far as I know, supported in all browsers.

Comment: In my opinion. This is the better answer. Here's quirksmodes take on onerror.....seems pretty safe to me. http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/error.html#t01

Comment: BTW, if error.jpg does not exist, this causes an infinite loop because it keeps trying to find the image, then onError is called again, it cannot find it, and the whole thing starts again.

Comment: @borq - true for all browsers except latest version on Chrome (v28). It only fires onerror once there. Have to set src to null first in Chrome, then set the image to get it to fire repeatedly.

Comment: To avoid infinite loop risk, just add a test:

<img src="foo.jpg" onerror="if (this.src != 'error.jog') this.src = 'error.jpg';">

Comment: Alternatively, you can write: `onerror="this.src='error.jpg';this.onerror='';"`

Comment: demo is not working in chrome, i can still see the error image

Comment: The CSS only solution does only work with an empty `alt` attribute on the image tag. At least on my version of Firefox. Please change
`<img src="nothere.jpg">` to `<img src="nothere.jpg" alt="">`.

Comment: When I load this fiddle in Chrome I see the broken image icon partially overlapped by the error-image. Unless this is a mistake on my part I would not consider that a solution.

Comment: I found that @DenilsonSáMaia solution works best, CSS one doesnt render in firefox, and jacquarg javascript solution still caused an infinite loop.

Comment: Worked for me after adding an alt with a whitespace character `alt=" "`.

Comment: CSS solution is useless. Does not work on FF.

Comment: it loads two images (in Chrome) if the first image is not broken, which is redundant

Comment: No Safari support (still) for the CSS solution: [test](https://jsfiddle.net/qsnpew30/show).

Answer (score 94):

Found this solution in Spring in Action 3rd Ed.

```
<img src="../resources/images/Image1.jpg" onerror="this.src='../resources/images/none.jpg'" />
```

**Update:**
This is not an HTML only solution... `onerror` is javascript

Comment: This works great. Here's an update with a fallback image on imgur:
<img src="a-missing-image.jpg" alt="" onerror="this.src='http:///i.imgur.com/hfM1J8s.png'">

Comment: it could lead to an infinite loop if the onerror src is also broken

Comment: To avoid the infinite loop, you can do `onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='../resources/images/none.jpg'"`

Answer (score 36):

a simple img-element is not very flexible so i combined it with a picture-element. this way no CSS is needed. when an error occurs, all srcset's are set to the fallback version. a broken link image is not showing up. it does not load unneeded image versions. the picture-element supports responsive design and multiple fallbacks for types that are not supported by the browser.

```
<picture>
    <source id="s1" srcset="image1_not_supported_by_browser.webp" type="image/webp">
    <source id="s2" srcset="image2_broken_link.png" type="image/png">
    <img src="image3_fallback.jpg" alt="" onerror="this.onerror=null;document.getElementById('s1').srcset=document.getElementById('s2').srcset=this.src;">
</picture>
```

Comment: this one is great! be aware of missing browser support https://caniuse.com/#feat=picture. consider using a polyfill or another solution if you need to support older browsers like IE11.

Comment: i tested IE 11 at least and it's falling back to the img element

Answer (score 21):

Simple and neat solution involving some good answers and comment.

```
<img src="foo.jpg" onerror="this.src='error.jpg';this.onerror='';">
```

It even solve infinite loop risk.

Worked for me.

Comment: onError is deprecated as per developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

Comment: onerror still seems to be supported https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#image_loading_errors

Comment: the funny thing is nobody knows why its deprecated https://github.com/mdn/sprints/issues/4014

Comment: It is no longer marked deprecated; apparently it was an MDN documentation mistake.  https://github.com/mdn/sprints/issues/4014#issuecomment-1874088209

Answer (score 17):

```
<style type="text/css">
img {
   background-image: url('/images/default.png')
}
</style>
```

Be sure to enter dimensions of image and whether you want the image to tile or not.

Comment: Doesn't most browsers show a 'broken link' image when the image is not found... In that case, setting the background would not solve the problem.

Answer (score 16):

I don't think it is possible using just HTML. However using javascript this should be doable. Bassicly we loop over each image, test if it is complete and if it's naturalWidth is zero then that means that it not found. Here is the code:

```
fixBrokenImages = function( url ){
    var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    var i=0, l=img.length;
    for(;i<l;i++){
        var t = img[i];
        if(t.naturalWidth === 0){
            //this image is broken
            t.src = url;
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
 window.onload = function() {
    fixBrokenImages('example.com/image.png');
 }
```

Tested in Chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 14):

```html
<img style="background-image: url(image1), url(image2);"></img>
```

Use background image that let you add multiple images.
My case: 
   image1 is the main image, this will get from some place (browser doing a request)
   image2 is a default local image to show while image1 is being loaded.
If image1 returns any kind of error, the user won't see any change and this will be clean for user experience

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds

Comment: This only works if image1 is completely opaque.  If it has transparency, like most icon images do, then image2 will show through.

Answer (score 11):

**If you're using Angular/jQuery then this might help...**

```
<img ng-src="{{item.url}}" altSrc="{{item.alt_url}}" onerror="this.src = $(this).attr('altSrc')">
```

**Explanation**

Assuming that `item` has a property `url` that might be null, when it is then the image will show up as broken. That triggers execution of `onerror` attribute expression, as described above. You need to override the `src` attribute as described above, but you will need jQuery to access your altSrc. Couldn't get it to work with vanilla JavaScript.

Might seem a little hacky but saved the day on my project.

Answer (score 9):

angular2:

```
<img src="{{foo.url}}" onerror="this.src='path/to/altimg.png'">
```

Comment: While this may work I don't think that it adds any new information. The onerror portion is just vanilla JavaScript and the src binding should already be known by Angular users

Answer (score 8):

An HTML only solution, where the only requirement is that you *know* the size of the image that you're inserting. Will not work for transparent images, as it uses `background-image` as a filler.

We can successfully use `background-image` to link the image that appears if the given image is missing. Then the only problem is the broken icon image - we can remove it by inserting a very big empty character, thus pushing the content outside the display of `img`.

```css
img {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/200x200");
  overflow: hidden;
}

img:before {
  content: " ";
  font-size: 1000px;
}
```

```html
This image is missing:
<img src="a.jpg" style="width: 200px; height: 200px"/><br/>
And is displaying the placeholder
```

---

An CSS only solution (Webkit only)

```css
img:before {
  content: " ";
  font-size: 1000px;
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/200x200");
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  margin-bottom: -16px;
}
```

```html
This image is there:
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/><br/>

This image is missing:
<img src="a.jpg"/><br/>
And is displaying the placeholder
```

Answer (score 8):

Update: 2022 (works on chrome still!!)

I recently had to build a fall back system which included any number of fallback images. Here's how I did it using a simple JavaScript function.

HTML

```
 <img src="some_image.tiff"
    onerror="fallBackImg(this);"
    data-src-1="some_image.png"
    data-src-2="another_image.jpg">
```

JavaScript

```
function fallBackImg(elem){
    elem.error = null;
    let index = elem.dataset.fallIndex || 1;
    elem.src = elem.dataset[`src-${index}`];
    elem.dataset.fallIndex = ++index;
}
```

I feel like it's a pretty lightweight way of handling many fallback images.

If you want "HTML only" then this

```
<img src="some_image.tiff"
    onerror="this.error = null;
        let i = this.dataset.i || 1;
        this.src = this.dataset[`src-${i}`];
        this.dataset.i = ++i;"
    data-src-1="some_image.png"
    data-src-2="another_image.jpg">
```

Comment: onError is deprecated as per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

Comment: Re being deprecated, not sure why it's marked that way. More here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59366589/28099

Answer (score 6):

A modulable version with **JQuery**, add this at the end of your file:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('img[data-src-error]').error(function() {
            var o = $(this);
            var errorSrc = o.attr('data-src-error');

            if (o.attr('src') != errorSrc) {
                o.attr('src', errorSrc);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

and on your `img` tag:

```
<img src="..." data-src-error="..." />
```

Answer (score 6):

React

```
<img
  src="https://example.com/does_not_exist.png"
  onError={(e) => {
    e.currentTarget.src = "https://example.com/default.png"
  }}
/>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to be sure the myriad number of clients (browsers) that will try to view your page. One aspect to consider is that email clients are defacto web browsers and may not handle such trickamajickery ...

As such you should ALSO include an alt/text with a DEFAULT WIDTH and HEIGHT, like this. This is a pure HTML solution.

```
alt="NO IMAGE" width="800" height="350"
```

So the other good answer would be slightly modified as follows:

```
<img src="foo.jpg" onerror="if (this.src != 'error.jpg') this.src = 'error.jpg';" alt="NO IMAGE" width="800" height="350">
```

I had issues with the object tag in Chrome, but I would imagine this would apply to that as well.

You can further style the alt/text to be VERY BIG ...

So my answer is use Javascript with a nice alt/text fallback.

I also found this interesting: [How to style an image's alt attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16671428/how-to-style-an-images-alt-attribute)

Answer (score 3):

**The above solution is incomplete**, it missed the attribute `src`.

`this.src` and `this.attribute('src')` are NOT the same, the first one contains the full reference to the image, for example `http://my.host/error.jpg`, but the attribute just keeps the original value, `error.jpg`

Correct solution

```
<img src="foo.jpg" onerror="if (this.src != 'error.jpg' && this.attribute('src') != 'error.jpg') this.src = 'error.jpg';" />
```

Comment: When using this code, I see `Uncaught TypeError: this.attribute is not a function` in Chrome 43.

Comment: onError is deprecated as per developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

Comment: Re being deprecated, not sure why it's marked that way.  More here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59366589/28099

Answer (score 3):

## 3 solutions for this:

Consider following html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  
   <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   <img id="imageId">
   <script src="setimage.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Solution one :**
reference this block of JS code inside the body tag of your html as 
`<script src="setimage.js"></script>` 

and set the src paths, the first is the one if there is an error, the next is the one you hope works first time :)

```
var img = document.getElementById("imageId")
       img.onerror = () => {
           img.src= "../error.png";
       }
       img.src= "../correct.webp.png";
```

**Solution two:**

this solution is almost the same, instead you will call the method, again at the end of your body within a script tag, but would supply the paths there.

```
function setImageWithFallback(mainImgPath, secondaryImgPath) {
   var img = document.getElementById("imageId")
       img.onerror = () => {
           img.src= mainImgPath;
       }
       img.src= secondaryImgPath;
}
```

**Solution three:**
if its just a single image, this would be the simplest :) simply set the onerror at the img tag

```
<img id="imageId" src="../correct.webp.png" 
onerror="if (this.src != '../error.png') this.src = '../error.png';">
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Angular 1.x you can include a directive that will allow you to fallback to any number of images. The fallback attribute supports a single url, multiple urls inside an array, or an angular expression using scope data:

```
<img ng-src="myFirstImage.png" fallback="'fallback1.png'" />
<img ng-src="myFirstImage.png" fallback="['fallback1.png', 'fallback2.png']" />
<img ng-src="myFirstImage.png" fallback="myData.arrayOfImagesToFallbackTo" />
```

Add a new fallback directive to your angular app module:

```
angular.module('app.services', [])
    .directive('fallback', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var errorCount = 0;

                // Hook the image element error event
                angular.element(element).bind('error', function (err) {
                    var expressionFunc = $parse(attrs.fallback),
                        expressionResult,
                        imageUrl;

                    expressionResult = expressionFunc(scope);

                    if (typeof expressionResult === 'string') {
                        // The expression result is a string, use it as a url
                        imageUrl = expressionResult;
                    } else if (typeof expressionResult === 'object' && expressionResult instanceof Array) {
                        // The expression result is an array, grab an item from the array
                        // and use that as the image url
                        imageUrl = expressionResult[errorCount];
                    }

                    // Increment the error count so we can keep track
                    // of how many images we have tried
                    errorCount++;
                    angular.element(element).attr('src', imageUrl);
                });
            }
        };
    }])
```

Answer (score 0):

For any image, just use this javascript code:

```
if (ptImage.naturalWidth == 0)
    ptImage.src = '../../../../icons/blank.png';
```

where `ptImage` is a `<img>` tag address obtained by `document.getElementById()`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Patrick's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/980910/737915) brilliant answer, for those of you who are searching for a cross-platform angular js solution, here you go:

```
<object type="image/png" data-ng-attr-data="{{ url || 'data:' }}">
    <!-- any html as a fallback -->
</object>
```

Here's a plunk where I was playing trying to find the right solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/nL6FQ6kMK33NJeW8DVDY?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

If you have created dynamic Web project and have placed the required image in WebContent then you can access the image by using below mentioned code in Spring MVC:

```
<img src="Refresh.png" alt="Refresh" height="50" width="50">
```

You can also create folder named img and place the image inside the folder img and place that img folder inside WebContent then you can access the image by using below mentioned code:

```
<img src="img/Refresh.png" alt="Refresh" height="50" width="50">
```

Answer (score 0):

I am adding `loading="lazy"` to `<img>` tag. In some cases it works.

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple Jquery that worked for me

```
        $(image).on('error', function(event) {
            imgage.attr('src', 'your_image.png');})
```

Answer (score -1):

Using Jquery you could do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("img").attr("src") != null)
    {
       if ($("img").attr("src").toString() == "")
       {
            $("img").attr("src", "images/default.jpg");
       }
    }
    else
    {
        $("img").attr("src", "images/default.jpg");
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Some CMS use **Markdown** to store Website content. It is also possible to define a fallback image in Markdown, just use the alt attribute:

```markdown
![fallback-image.jpg](image-notloading.jpg)
```

This generates the following HTML output:

```
<img src="image-notloading.jpg" alt="fallback-image.jpg">
```

You need a little javascript to make the fallback mechanism work:

```html
<script>
document.querySelectorAll("img").forEach(function(el){
    el.setAttribute("onerror","this.src=this.alt;this.onerror='';");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Well!!
I found this way convenient , check for the height attribute of image to be 0, then you can overwrite the src attribute with default image:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image

```
 image.setAttribute('src','../icons/<some_image>.png');
  //check the height attribute.. if image is available then by default it will 
  //be 100 else 0
  if(image.height == 0){                                       
       image.setAttribute('src','../icons/default.png');
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

HTML Part:

```
<img [ngStyle]="{'width.px': size}" src="assets/svg/{{code}}.svg"
(error)="handleFlagError($event)">
```

JS Part:

```
function handleFlagError($event) {
        $event.target.src = 'assets/svg/base.svg';
      }
```