# How to display a default image in case the source does not exists

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code inside myasp.net MVC  web application:-

```
 <a href="~/Content/uploads/@(item.ID).png"><img class="thumbnailimag" src="~/Content/uploads/@(item.ID).png"  /></a>   @Html.ActionLink(item.Name,"Details","DataCenter", new{id = item.ID},null)
```

And the following CSS:

```
.thumbnailimag {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    border:thin blue;
    background-image:url("/Content/uploads/virtual-data-center.jpg");
}
```

But if the image does not exists each bowser will treat it differently . I set a background image but still on IE it will display a “X” over the default image , as follow:-
[image]

Can anyone advice if there is a way to display a default image if the src does not exists?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inputting a default image in case the src arribute of an html <img> is not valid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980855/inputting-a-default-image-in-case-the-src-arribute-of-an-html-img-is-not-valid)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery/Javascript to replace broken images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's far better to handle this server-side:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static string ImageOrDefault(this HtmlHelper helper, string filename)
    {
        var imagePath = uploadsDirectory + filename + ".png";
        var imageSrc = File.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(imagePath))
                           ? imagePath : defaultImage;

        return imageSrc;
    }

    private static string defaultImage = "/Content/DefaultImage.png";
    private static string uploadsDirectory = "/Content/uploads/";
}
```

Then your view is simplified to:

```
<img src="@Html.ImageOrDefault(item.ID)" />
```

Comment: but where it is better to create this class, under the Controller folder or under the Model folder ? thnaks

Comment: @JohnJohn I tend to create a new folder called `Extensions` or `Helpers` and put it in there.  In order for that to work though, you'd need to add the namespace to your `~/Views/Web.config` file (make sure it's that one and not the `Web.config` in the root of your project).  Just look for the element `<system.web.webPages.razor>`.  In there, you'll find a few namespaces already added. Under those, you'd add something like: `<add namespace="YourProject.Extensions" />`.

Answer (score 31):

Sure, for your images use:

`<img src="fails/to/load.png" onerror="this.src='path/to/replacement/image.jpg'" />`

There isnt a solution in CSS, it will require JS to be either applied to each `<img>` tag or a top level handler to replace the `onerror` event for all images.

Comment: +1 though I fear [if error.jpg does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980855/inputting-a-default-image-in-case-the-src-arribute-of-an-html-img-is-not-valid#comment21349757_980948)

Comment: +1 Thanks @SW4 (and John John for asking the question) saved me a bunch of time/code/experimentation/failure/heartbreak.

Comment: Perhaps `onerror="this.onerror = null; this.src='path/to/replacement/image.jpg'"`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add some js, for example add an event listener to img tag:

```
<img id="something" data-isloaded="false" onload="$(this).data('isloaded', 'true')" />
```

Then you can check if image is loaded:

```
if ($('#myimage').data('isloaded') === 'false' ) {
    // not loaded, do stuff here
    // add some replacement thumbnail
    // or set background image to the parent element
}
```