# JavaScript: Is there an error property for failed image requests?

Tags: javascript, image, html, dom

An HTML `<img>` element has a boolean `complete` property, which is `true` if the image has successfully loaded (or if it hasn't yet been assigned a `src`). It also has an `onload` event, which fires when the image successfully loads, and an `onerror` event, which fires when the image fails to load (e.g. due to a broken link, corrupt image, or offline network).

Now... what I want to know is if there is **a property on an image element that denotes that the image has *already* failed to load**. Assume that I cannot use the `onerror` event, because the script may only have access to the image after the event has fired. What we are looking for is a simple boolean lookup property like `complete` that says "the loading of this image was already attempted, and it failed". (Which I don't see in the spec, but I'm wondering if I'm missing something).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` for a similar effect in almost all browsers (IE8 and below do not support this property). The `naturalXX` properties contain the original height/width of the image, before modifications through HTML/CSS attributes/styling. So if `naturalWidth == 0`, you know the image has failed to load.

(Note that you can't use the standard `width` or `height` properties, since those will return the size of the notfound placeholder image.)

```
document.getElementById("image").naturalWidth ? "success" : "fail"
```

If you're just trying to change the not found placeholder image, there's a [nifty HTML solution for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/980910/1122351):

```
<object data="https://stackoverflow.com/does-not-exist.png">
  <img src="https://stackoverflow.com/content/img/so/logo.png">
</object>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K3dwX/1/

**PS:** [Potential solution for IE6+](http://jacklmoore.com/notes/naturalwidth-and-naturalheight-in-ie/)