# Setting a default src to img element

Tags: asp.net

Some people set default src to img element in the following way:

```
<img src="foo.jpg" onerror="this.src='default.jpg'" />
```

I think it's not the best way because a additional http request will be sent when onerror event be fired, and our log component will log the worthless error message.

I think I can do in following way:

Create a HttpHandler(.ashx) to send appropriate image to client. So I can write a img in page like this: `<img src=‘ImageHandler.ashx?id=foo.jpg’/>`. App will check whether the image(`foo.jpg`) exists or not, then decides to send foo.jpg or default.jpg.

Is it right? Do you have better resolution?

Comment: Are you not in control of the web server, or how come you have to check if the images exist? Are you referencing images hosted by others?

Comment: Yes, I'm using asp.net. I will check the file by Method in System.IO  -File.Exists(filePath).

Comment: @Domi.Zhang try to avoid server side operation for this scenario...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah there is a way :

```
<object data="http://aaa.com/does-not-exist.png">
    <img src="http://aaa.com/content/img/so/logo.png">
  </object>
```

how ever you should tyry it with the Browser compatibility.

another solutiuon is :

```
<style type="text/css">
img {
   background-image: url('/images/default.png')
}
</style>
```

if the inside image doesn't exists , the outer will be performed.

After a srarch : this question was asked before here :

[Inputting a default image in case the src attribute of an html <img> is not valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980855/inputting-a-default-image-in-case-the-src-arribute-of-an-html-img-is-not-valid)