# Default image if src image not found causing annoying redraw on every re-render

Tags: jquery, html, image

So I'm using this [awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980855/inputting-a-default-image-in-case-the-src-arribute-of-an-html-img-is-not-valid/980910#980910) to embed a default image if the one I'm looking for is not found. That all works great on initial load, but I have some click listeners on the cell which holds this object/image tag, and every time it gets clicked, I have to rerender the cell using jQuery.

When the rerender happens on cells which the image exists, everything works great. But for cells that need to use the default image, there's a rerendering/redrawing quick little flash that the user sees because it tries to render the first image which doesn't exist, and that fails, and then it goes and gets the default one. But that little dance causing the image to go away and then come back in a split second is kind of annoying.  Is there a way to fix that? Like a "Don't reflash this section until you know which image to load" kind of thing?

Snippet looks something like this :

```
<body>   
  <object data="http://example.com/<@ someImageBasedOnSomeVariable @>">
    <img src="http://example.com/default.png">
  </object>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the [`.error`](http://api.jquery.com/error/) and [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function:

```
$("img")
.load(function() { //run stuff normally })
.error(function() { //run stuff with the default image })
```