# Conditionally changing mime type using jQuery and Modernizr

Tags: jquery, object, svg, mime-types, modernizr

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="/images/ampersand.svg"></object>
<object type="image/png" data="/images/ampersand.png"></object>
```

Basically, using jQuery, I want to change the .SVG one to the .PNG one, for browsers with no svg support (I'll use modenizr to detect that).

I've tried a bunch of different ways with no joy.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I learned about [this (IMHO truly awesome) HTML only solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980855/inputting-a-default-image-in-case-the-src-arribute-of-an-html-img-is-not-valid#answer-980910).  Works perfectly to give a fallback in IE 6:

```
<object data="/images/ampersand.svg">
  <img src="/images/ampersand.png">
</object>
```

Comment: note that there's a drawback: it will cause browsers to download both resources.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function supportsSvg() {
        return document.implementation.hasFeature("http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Shape", "1.0");
    }
    if (!supportsSvg()) {
        $('object[type="image/svg+xml"]').prop('type', 'image/png').prop('data', function (_, old) {
            return old.replace('.svg', '.png');
        });
    }
});
```

---

Wrap code in DOM ready

Read

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Wouldn't you require `supportsSvg()` as it is a function you are calling?

Comment: @Lugia101101 yeah missed typing too fast. ty updated.

Comment: Do I add this to the head, or before the /body?

Comment: @PaulBrowne check updated answer .Now you can write this code anywhere  in the page.

Comment: Didn't work, check http://paul-browne.github.io/articlr/ the ampersand should'nt fill the screen

Comment: @PaulBrowne Try `if (supportsSvg()) {` instead of `if (!supportsSvg()) {`