# HTML5 Can I use <img> with <source>

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I wonder if I can use tag `<img>` like `<video>`. When I want to add a video to my website I use:

```
<video>
   <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

The result is that browser loads only first file, which are supported. It's possible to do the same with `<img>`? I want to add icons in svg and png/jpg format, so browser will loads the one, which support. Or maybe is better to do it with some Javascript to detect `user-agent` and then replace graphics in other format?

Comment: This solution might work for you:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/980910/2414886

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot combine `<img>` with `<source>`. It was deliberately not allowed, because it created backwards-compatibility problems. *However*, for this use case, the new element [`<picture>`](http://responsiveimages.org/) was introduced:

```
<picture>
  <source type="image/svg+xml"
    srcset="image.svg">
  <img src="fallback.jpg" alt="">
</picture>
```

It is [gaining support](http://caniuse.com/#search=picture), but since it's brand-new, some important browsers are missing yet.

Comment: But, how about support? At now `<picture>` is only supported in Chrome and Opera. So it's not solution to widely support at this time.

Comment: You could use a JavaScript polyfill (with [Picturefill](http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/) the most popular). This way, you can use the forward-proof mark-up also in older browsers.

Comment: Ok, thanks :) so JS actually is the one posible and rational way to do it.

Comment: Well, it depends on your use case. You could load the SVG with an `<object type="image/svg+xml">` and write an `<img>` in it as fallback. However, when you want to use the SVG as icons, this will probably not fit your bill (most likely because of `click` event issues inside the `<object>`). That would be a markup-only solution specifically for the SVG/PNG combo with close to 100% browser support.