# Echo link in php, and insert php in alt of <img>

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have an HTML tag `<img>` for specific products, however some products don't have images since their similar products already have the same. I want the viewer who reached these image-less products to be able to click on a link and get to the similar products. Now the `<img>` is like this:

```
<img src="../imgs/product/<?php echo $productName;?>.png" alt="No image for this item. Please refer to its similar item: <?php echo $alt; ?> "/>
```

Then I want the $alt part to be a link to the similar product, so I wrote:

```
<?php 
    $alt = '<a href=\"singleproduct.php?singleItem=' 
         . $similarProduct .'\">'. $similarProduct. '</a>'; 
?>
```

It's not possible to print out the link no matter how I revise the style of quotes. Just wondering if it's not possible at all to insert an `<a>` inside of `<img>`...? If not, how to make this work?

Comment: you don't need to escape `\"` inside your single-quoted statement since you're using `$alt = '...';` as opposed to `$alt = "...";` - and why the jquery/css tags?

Comment: @Fred-ii- the `$alt` is going into that image, I think, where the double quotes are being used for the `alt` attribute in the HTML. Not sure if the `alt` can support links..

Comment: you're going about this the wrong way. What you're trying to do translates to `<img <a href></a>>` rather than `<img><a href></a>` It's hard to say exactly what you want to do here really. and no, the alt tag does not support href.

Comment: I don't think you can use the `alt` attribute to accomplish your goal. Here's a definition for the `alt` attribute *The alt attribute provides alternative information for an image if a user for some reason cannot view it (because of slow connection, an error in the src attribute, or if the user uses a screen reader).*

Comment: you can do `$alt = 'I am an alt tag';` though or `$alt = $similarProduct;` if you have a message assigned for that. If you want to add the href, you'll need to place it "after" your `<img>` tag, it can't be part of the alt tag. Another thing, ternary operator.

Comment: you can't nest html like that. `alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(..); ?>"` would probably work, because then you're not embedding "html", just htmll-encoded characters

Comment: well you guys sort this out. @ me if you want me to submit my comments to an answer. I have to go take care of stuff ;-)

Comment: @chris85 This has been a *"talk amongst ourselves"* type of question. I had time to cut, split and pile a cord of wood already, and still nothing ;-) and no, alt does not support href.

Comment: I have no idea what this discussion is about. Why is everybody, including the OP, ignoring the  _"some products don't have images"_ part of the question? I can't believe nobody pointed out yet that if there is no image, the solution is to not use an `<img>` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have a html tag in a html attibute. If you wan't a full html fallback, take a look at [Inputting a default image in case the src attribute of an html <img> is not valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980855/inputting-a-default-image-in-case-the-src-arribute-of-an-html-img-is-not-valid)

Comment: Indeed, sorry about that. I'm new to stackoverflow and didn't notice the show more comments button @Fred-ii-