# Is there a way to provide a fallback for missing srcset images?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, retina

I'm trying to implement retina (2x) images across my website. Our pages are built from templates where we just use standard inline images:

```
<img src="path/to/image.png" />
```

I thought I could be clever and update this with `srcset`:

```
<img src="path/to/image.png" srcset="path/to/image@2x.png 2x" />
```

However, we don't have 2x variants of many of these images yet.

So I tested the `srcset` attribute with a non-existent image specified as the 2x resource, thinking that since it wasn't available, the browser would just display the standard image as specified in the `src`. Instead, it tried to load the missing 2x resource and displayed a broken image on the page.

Is there any way to have the browser display the 1x image as a fallback if the 2x image doesn't exist? Otherwise, I can't update the templates until *every single image* has a 2x variant, or we'll end up with broken images all over the place.

Comment: You can try `onerror` event of image to load fallback image.If you don't want scripts then [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980855/inputting-a-default-image-in-case-the-src-attribute-of-an-html-img-is-not-vali) is also a good solution

Comment: isn't it possible to just not use `srcset` for images you don't have? Why would you want broken link in your HTML in the first place?

Comment: No, because there's a ton of pages all generated from this same template. If I want to use `srcset` on one page, I have to use it for all of them.

Comment: How did you end up dealing with it?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no. All images in the srcset must exist. Otherwise, you'll end up with broken images all over the place.

Saying that, if you use `onerror`, you can have one fallback image:

```
<img src="path/to/image.png" srcset="path/to/image@2x.png 2x" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='path/to/image.png'" />
```