# Customize laravel HTML elements

Tags: laravel

Can laravel built-in html elements be overridden? for example, consider HTML:image tag. I am wondering if I can override it in order to show 'no_available_image.svg' when the given image path doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't override an `<img>` tag (or you shouldn't), but there are other ways to achieve an image fallback.

Also, take in account that HTML:image tag is not a Laravel built-in element, is just HTML and Laravel has nothing to do here.

---

## Blade PHP solution

Check that file exists. If not, it will `echo` the fallback image.

```
@if (file_exists(public_path('path/to/image.jpg')))
    <img src="{{ asset('path/to/image.jpg') }}">
@else
    <img src="{{ asset('images/no_available_image.svg') }}">
@endif
```

---

## Vue + Blade solution

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980855/inputting-a-default-image-in-case-the-src-attribute-of-an-html-img-is-not-vali), you can create a Vue component like this:

*ImgFallback.vue*

```
<template>
    <object :data="src" type="image/png">
        <img :src="fallback" />
    </object>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            src: String,
            fallback: String
        }
    }
</script>
```

then register it in your `app.js`

```
Vue.component('img-fallback', require('./components/ImgFallback.vue'));
```

So then in your blade templates you can use:

```
<img-fallback 
    src="{{ asset('wrong_image_path') }}" 
    fallback="{{ asset('images/no_available_image.svg') }}">
</img-fallback>
```

---

### Reusing code

Since you will be using blade and the same fallback image in all cases, you don't want to repeat the fallback attribute everytime, so you can create a blade template called for example `image.blade.php` and put in the javascript or PHP option. Then in your views call:

```
@include('image', [ 'path' => 'path/to/your/image.jpg' ])
```

And use the `$path` variable to fill the `src` attribute in the `image.blade.php` file.

```
@if (file_exists(public_path($path)))
    <img src="{{ asset($path) }}">
@else
    <img src="{{ asset('images/no_available_image.svg') }}">
@endif
```

or

```
<img-fallback 
    src="{{ asset($src) }}" 
    fallback="{{ asset('images/no_available_image.svg') }}">
</img-fallback>
```

Comment: I found a simple solution. look here: <img src="{{ image('path/to/image.jpg') }}">. while image is a helper method which check if the path exists return asset($path) otherwise it returns $path('no_available_image.svg'); it works! simple and stupid.