# Fallback image if image is not found in picture source tag

Tags: html, image, fallback

How can I add a fallback image if the image specified in the source tag is missing? For example

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="image.webp 1x, image@2x.webp 2x" type="image/webp">
  <img srcset="image.jpg 1x, image@2x.jpg 2x" src="image.jpg" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.srcset='not-found.jpg 1x, not-found@2x.jpg 2x'">
</picture>
```

If image.webp is missing, how can I show a fallback image? Putting `onerror="this.src='fallback.jpg'"` on the `img` tag works if the browser doesn't support webp images, but same If I put that code on the `source` tag doesn't work

EDIT

Updated the code, it now works on browser which doesn't support webp images (safari) but I'm still not able to show a `not-found.webp` images for other browsers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inputting a default image in case the src attribute of an html <img> is not valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980855/inputting-a-default-image-in-case-the-src-attribute-of-an-html-img-is-not-vali)

Comment: @Devinloper nope, it doesn't use the `picture` tag but a single `object` tag

Answer (score 3):

[Can we bring the image URL from WordPress shortcode?](https://www.animationvideo.co/amit-biswas/?cx__name=Rahul&profile__img=https://res.cloudinary.com/animationvideo/image/upload/v1578246850/Team/Rahul_Giri.jpg)

```
<script>
function onError() {
  this.onerror = null;
  this.parentNode.children[0].srcset = this.parentNode.children[1].srcset = this.src;
}
</script>

<picture>
   <source srcset="[ifsoDKI type="querystring" parameter="profile__img" />
   <source srcset="[ifsoDKI type="querystring" parameter="profile__img" />

   <img src="https://www.animationvideo.co/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/A-V.png" alt="logo" onerror="onError.call(this)" />
</picture>
```

Answer (score 2):

1st Picture tag : Success case where webp is successfully loaded without any fallback case

2nd Picture tag: Failed to load webp (404) then fallback and load the jpg image

Full artile in [hectane.com](http://hectane.com/blog/fallback-image-if-image-not-found-in-picture-source-tag)

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Image Fallback</title>
  <script>
    function onError() {
      this.onerror = null;
      this.parentNode.children[0].srcset = this.parentNode.children[1].srcset = this.src;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Success condition webp is avalibale and onerror is not called-->
  <picture>
    <source srcset="
         https://assets.hectane.com/fallback-image-if-image-not-found-in-picture-source-tag/listing.webp
        " type="image/webp" />
    <source srcset="
          https://assets.hectane.com/fallback-image-if-image-not-found-in-picture-source-tag/listing.png
        " type="image/png" />
    <img src="https://assets.hectane.com/fallback-image-if-image-not-found-in-picture-source-tag/listing.jpg" alt="success" onerror="onError.call(this)" />
  </picture>
  <picture>
   <source srcset="
         https://assets.hectane.com/fallback-image-if-image-not-found-in-picture-source-tag/listing1.webp
        " type="image/webp" />
    <source srcset="
          https://assets.hectane.com/fallback-image-if-image-not-found-in-picture-source-tag/listing.webp
        " type="image/png" />
    <img src="https://assets.hectane.com/fallback-image-if-image-not-found-in-picture-source-tag/listing.jpg" alt="fall back jpg called" onerror="onError.call(this)" />
  </picture>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm using this to solve infinite loop when my webp is getting 404.

Comment: What i do instead of changing srcset, is to remove the webp source. Using `this.parentNode.children[0].remove();`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the attribute `src` used for `source` tag under `picture` element is wrong. The `source` tag has `srcset` attribute to accept the image path.

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="/path/to/image1.webp" type="image/webp">
  <source srcset="/path/to/image1.jpg" type="image/jpeg">

  <img src="/path/to/fallbackImage1.jpg">
</picture>
```

Secondly, you're not treating the fallback `img` tag correctly as per the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture).

> The HTML  element contains zero or more  elements and
>   one  element to offer alternative versions of an image for
>   different display/device scenarios.
>
> **The browser will consider each child  element and choose the
>   best match among them. If no matches are found—or the browser doesn't
>   support the  element—the URL of the  element's src
>   attribute is selected. The selected image is then presented in the
>   space occupied by the  element**.

The `img` tag used inside `picture` element works only when the browser compatibility issue triggers.

You need to achieve this via other workaround script, as default mechanism won't fulfill the needful.

Also, could you elaborate your exact requirement of using `picture` element?

Comment: My bad, the example was different from my actual code (I was using the srcset tag properly). I've update the question with my new code. I'm using the picture element beacuse I have to use webp images where possibile and jpg images in the other cases

Comment: @andyts93 Thank you for the clarification and appropriate edit in the question. However, the thing that you're trying to do with onerror works on <img> and not on <picture> and it's <source>. To my knowledge, you can't expect "not-found.webp" image to load when the image is not present at the path you mentioned for srcset of source tag of picture element.