# How to Set Default Image in Html If the original image is not visible or gives Error

Tags: html

How can we set default image in case if original image is not loaded or gives error and shows only alt text in place of image in html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inputting a default image in case the src attribute of an html <img> is not valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980855/inputting-a-default-image-in-case-the-src-attribute-of-an-html-img-is-not-vali)

Comment: share what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

try this way

```html
<img id="currentPhoto" src="SomeImage.jpg" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png'" alt="" width="100" height="120">
```

Use `onerror` for this issue