# Is it possible to define a global 'broken link' image per page when the image is not found using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I'm working on a site and receive HTML content from another source and that source contains images it will show a "broken image" image.

Is there a way for me to define the broken image for the entire page using HTML or CSS and as an absolute last resort JavaScript function. A HTML or CSS option is preferred?

For example, let's sat your job was to replace every broken image with a picture of a rose. Would love CSS or HTML solution.

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

img:invalid {
  border: 5px solid #ff0000;
}

img:error {
  border: 5px solid #ff0000;
}

div {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>Here is some content next to an image that does not exist  <img id="image" src="nothing.jpg"> 
</div>
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

There are new CSS error selectors like invalid and error. Would it be a good idea to consider a pseudo-selector to match broken images?

This question wants to request answers related to those solutions.

Related but not CSS preferred:
[Inputting a default image in case the src attribute of an html <img> is not valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980855/inputting-a-default-image-in-case-the-src-attribute-of-an-html-img-is-not-vali)

Comment: Question updated to include CSS invalid and error pseudo selectors that. Please reopen.

Comment: If all the images were opaque, you could simply set a background-image via CSS, but maybe it's even better fixing the links no? To do so, simply append a <base>  element pointing to the original source's location.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doubtful this is possible outside of JS.

Add an error event listener to the image. On error, reassign the `src` attribute to your 404 image. For example, using your HTML and your avatar as the 404 image:

```js
for (const image of document.querySelectorAll('img')) {
  image.addEventListener('error', () => {
    image.src = 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e3aa08907388338521f3d9cec7a13d32?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG';
  });
}
```

```css
#image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

div {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>Here is some content next to an image that does not exist  <img id="image" src="nothing.jpg"> 
</div>
```

If you happen to control the server all the images are hosted on, you could also add a handler in case no matching path is found for a requested image, and return the placeholder 404 image instead.

Comment: If I run that loop after the document is loaded, "DOMContentLoaded" would it still trigger the error events?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('img')` only selects elements currently in the document. If you need dynamic images too, either use event delegation or attach a listener when the image gets inserted.