# Cannot get HTML5 Picture Source to work correctly

Tags: html, image

I'm testing out the following HTML5 Picture element, but I can't get it to show the correct source.

I would like the default image type to be 'webp', then 'jpg' as a fallback.

In this test, the webp image does not exist, so I was expecting the jpg to load instead.

But when trying on Chrome and Safari, it only fails to find the first source and does not try to load the existing jpg. So the picture is either blank or has a question mark icon.

Is there something wrong with the following code?

```
<picture class="item-slide" data-slideid="1">
  <source srcset="https://imgnotexist.com/test.webp" type="image/webp">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeSoC.jpg">
</picture>
```

**Solution**

This was actually the code I needed to use, and seems to work on most browsers.

```
<object data="https://imgnotexist.com/test.webp" type="image/webp">
 <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeSoC.jpg">
</object>
```

Comment: Note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for `<source>`

Comment: Good to know. I guess it's just because most elements have closing tags and I've seen so many examples where the img tag is self closed, I've assumed it to be the correct way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<img>` is only used if none of the `<source>` tags matches the media selection.  If a `<source>` tag matches, as yours does, then that's the one that will be displayed.  In your example, the `<img>` will never be used.

There's no way to do an "image does not exist" fallback without using Javascript.  That seems like a strange desire.

Comment: There is [Inputting a default image in case the src attribute of an html <img> is not valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980855/inputting-a-default-image-in-case-the-src-attribute-of-an-html-img-is-not-vali), but that isn't using the behavior of the `<picture>` element.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I misunderstood the principle of the fallback showing only whether the browser supported the sources format, and not whether the image existed or not!

Answer (score 1):

If the browser supports WebP and the WebP image is specified as the first source, it will try to load it. If the WebP image doesn't exist or can't be loaded (for example, if the URL is incorrect), it will not automatically fall back to the  element.

To achieve the behavior you're looking for, you might need to restructure your code a bit. You can try using the onerror attribute on the  element to trigger a fallback if the WebP image fails to load.

If the WebP source fails to load, it will trigger the onerror event and set the srcset of the source element to the JPEG image.

Please note that browser behavior might change over time, so it's always a good idea to test in various browsers to ensure consistent behavior.

Comment: Thanks Methsara, this is a great answer too. I did look into the onerror, but apparently that has been deprecated and should not be used - https://caniuse.com/mdn-html_elements_img_onerror